# eclipse checkstyle custom checks with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, maven, checkstyle

I've written some custom checkstyle checks and stored them in a jar to use with the maven checkstyle plugin. I've used this same jar for for the eclipse checkstyle plugin. If I need to update the custom checks, it's easy in maven (just update the version in the pom). To update the plugin, I need to manually replace that plugin file in eclipse. Is there a way to automatically keep these 2 files in sync?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `maven-eclipse-plugin` and add the checkstyle builder and checkstyle nature with custom configuration that indicates which checks to use. 
Since you already have the custom checks inside a jar, you have to add a dependency to that jar inside the maven-eclipse-plugin. 
It's better explained [here](http://jgonian.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/maven-checkstyle-and-eclipse/)